# Removing parentheses at the beginning of string

Tags: regex, sas

I want to remove text in parentheses which is only before the string like:
(bc2) xxxx. How I can do this using regex?

Comment: What did you try?  What is the result you want for your example string?  Note your example doesn't have any brackets, neither square brackets nor curly ones, just parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression `s/([()])//g`

[ ] is used to create a character set. My character set contains ( and ). So overall, substitute ( and ) with empty string.